# How to filter the array of objects?

Tags: javascript

I have a table

[image]

And this table as array with objects, one object = one row of the table

```
var list = [
    { "n1": 18, "n2": 1, "n3": 5, "n4": 17 },
    { "n1": 1, "n2": 2, "n3": 11, "n4": 6 },
    { "n1": 1, "n2": 5, "n3": 11, "n4": 12 },
    { "n1": 6, "n2": 17, "n3": 12, "n4": 1 },
    { "n1": 4, "n2": 7, "n3": 8, "n4": 20 },
    { "n1": 2, "n2": 3, "n3": 8, "n4": 7 },
    { "n1": 2, "n2": 8, "n3": 7, "n4": 6 },
    { "n1": 14, "n2": 15, "n3": 11, "n4": 10 },
    { "n1": 11, "n2": 8, "n3": 16, "n4": 15 },
    { "n1": 20, "n2": 4, "n3": 8, "n4": 7 },
    { "n1": 11, "n2": 12, "n3": 6, "n4": 14 },
    { "n1": 1, "n2": 5, "n3": 12, "n4": 11 },
    { "n1": 17, "n2": 12, "n3": 5, "n4": 1 },
    { "n1": 8, "n2": 9, "n3": 13, "n4": 19 },
    { "n1": 8, "n2": 9, "n3": 19, "n4": 15 },
    { "n1": 10, "n2": 9, "n3": 15, "n4": 8 },
    { "n1": 11, "n2": 12, "n3": 17, "n4": 6 },
    { "n1": 8, "n2": 7, "n3": 20, "n4": 4 }
]
```

I need to remove rows with the same numbers and leave one of them. The numbers in the row can be in different order.

Visual result, table after filtering:

[image]

Comment: Also add your current attempt.

Comment: @justDan The answer below is the only attempt

Comment: @Jac How do you know this? Are you somehow affiliated with the OP? Is the answerer?

Comment: @HereticMonkey I am a psychic, I had a vision last night... I saw no attempt from the author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to convert list to array of unique numbers:

For each object in list,

sort the number values:

```
const vals = Object.values(obj).sort((a, b) => a - b);
```

form a string hash of the number values to be stored in a hash object:

```
let valuesHashed = {};
...
let hash = vals.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + "," + String(curr));
... 
valuesHashed[hash] = true;
```

then check that subsequent objects in list are in the hash object.

```js
var list = [
  { n1: 18, n2: 1, n3: 5, n4: 17 },
  { n1: 1, n2: 2, n3: 11, n4: 6 },
  { n1: 1, n2: 5, n3: 11, n4: 12 },
  { n1: 6, n2: 17, n3: 12, n4: 1 },
  { n1: 4, n2: 7, n3: 8, n4: 20 },
  { n1: 2, n2: 3, n3: 8, n4: 7 },
  { n1: 2, n2: 8, n3: 7, n4: 6 },
  { n1: 14, n2: 15, n3: 11, n4: 10 },
  { n1: 11, n2: 8, n3: 16, n4: 15 },
  { n1: 20, n2: 4, n3: 8, n4: 7 },
  { n1: 11, n2: 12, n3: 6, n4: 14 },
  { n1: 1, n2: 5, n3: 12, n4: 11 },
  { n1: 17, n2: 12, n3: 5, n4: 1 },
  { n1: 8, n2: 9, n3: 13, n4: 19 },
  { n1: 8, n2: 9, n3: 19, n4: 15 },
  { n1: 10, n2: 9, n3: 15, n4: 8 },
  { n1: 11, n2: 12, n3: 17, n4: 6 },
  { n1: 8, n2: 7, n3: 20, n4: 4 }
];

let valuesHashed = {};
let uniques = [];
list.forEach(obj => {
  // create array of sorted values
  const vals = Object.values(obj).sort((a, b) => a - b);
  // form hash string of sorted values, use has as key to hash object
  let hash = vals.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + "," + String(curr));
  // add object to uniques if not yet in hash object
  if (!valuesHashed[hash]) {
    uniques.push(obj);
  }
  // add vales to hash object
  valuesHashed[hash] = true;
});

console.log("valuesHashed:", valuesHashed);

console.log("uniques:", uniques);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with pure functions:

```
const memory = list.map(item => ({
   item, key: Object.values(item).sort().toString()
}));

const uniqObjects = memory.reduce((acc, {key, item}) =>
    !acc.memo.has(key) ?
        ({uniqObjects: [...acc.uniqObjects, item], memo: acc.memo.add(key)}) : acc
       ,{uniqObjects: [], memo: new Set()}).uniqObjects;
```